# Pagination on my custom blog page template Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have create a custom blog page template but the problem is that i am not able to insert pagination links yet i want to display pagination links next and previous on the bottom of blogs what should i do....

here is my code

```
<?php /*
Template Name: My Blog Page
*/
?>

                <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9">
                    <!-- Blog Post -->
                    <?php

                    $args = array('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 10,     'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1, 'category_name' => 'blog', );
                    $post_type_data = new WP_Query($args);
                    while ($post_type_data->have_posts()):
                        $post_type_data->the_post();
                        global $more;
                        $more = 0; ?>
                        <div class="row blog-row" style="padding: 20px 0;border- bottom: 1px solid #A9A9A9;">
                            <div style="width: 50%;float: left">
                            <div class="feature-image img-overlay">
                                <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
                                    <?php $default = array('class' => 'img-responsive');
                                    the_post_thumbnail('wl_blog_img', $default); ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="feature-content" style="padding-left: 15px;display: inline-block;width: 50%">
                                <h3 class="h3-blog-title">
                                    <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo the_title(); ?></a>
                                </h3>
                                <span style="padding-right: 5px"><i class="icon-picture"></i></span>
                                <span style="padding-right: 5px"><i class="icon-time"></i><?php echo get_the_date('j'); ?> <?php echo the_time('M'); ?>, <?php echo the_time('Y'); ?></span>
                                <span style="padding-right: 5px"><i class="icon-user"></i><a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_author(); ?></a></span><br><br>

                                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                <a class="my-btn" href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="feature-details1">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <!-- //Blog Post// -->
                </div>
```

Comment: 'offset' => 0 change every page 'offset' => 10 , every page change variable

Comment: $args = array('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 10,     'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1, 'category_name' => 'blog','offset' => 0  ); then change off set value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following code for pagination

```
 <?php /*
    Template Name: My Blog Page
    */
 ?><div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9">
                    <!-- Blog Post -->
                    <?php
                    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                    $args = array('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 2,     'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1, 'category_name' => 'blog', 'paged' => $paged );

                    $post_type_data = new WP_Query($args);

                    set_query_var('page',$paged);
                    while ($post_type_data->have_posts()):
                    $post_type_data->the_post();
                    global $more;
                        $more = 0; ?>
                        <div class="row blog-row" style="padding: 20px 0;border- bottom: 1px solid #A9A9A9;">
                            <div style="width: 50%;float: left">
                            <div class="feature-image img-overlay">
                                <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
                                    <?php $default = array('class' => 'img-responsive');
                                    the_post_thumbnail('wl_blog_img', $default); ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="feature-content" style="padding-left: 15px;display: inline-block;width: 50%">
                                <h3 class="h3-blog-title">
                                    <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo the_title(); ?></a>
                                </h3>
                                <span style="padding-right: 5px"><i class="icon-picture"></i></span>
                                <span style="padding-right: 5px"><i class="icon-time"></i><?php echo get_the_date('j'); ?> <?php echo the_time('M'); ?>, <?php echo the_time('Y'); ?></span>
                                <span style="padding-right: 5px"><i class="icon-user"></i><a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_author(); ?></a></span><br><br>

                                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                <a class="my-btn" href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="feature-details1">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
<div class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Newer posts');?></div>
                        <div class="nav-next alignright"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts &raquo;', $post_type_data->max_num_pages ); ?></div>
                    <!-- //Blog Post// -->
                </div>
```

Comment: hello bhumi offset=>'' also use for that